# Google Analytics filter PayPal referral

Tags: paypal, filter, google-analytics

I've been trying to filter out the referral links from the PayPal CGI script for a client in Google Analytics. The referral path in GA is mostly /cgibin/webscr although I just saw one with /us/cgi-bin/webscr/.

I've tried a predefined filter ("Exclude traffic from the ISP domain that contains paypal.com") and two custom filters:
- Exclude Campaign Referral Path: .*/paypal.com/cgibin/webscr
- Exclude Referral: .*/paypal.com/cgibin/webscr

It seems I've filtered out some, but not all. Anyone know any way to knock out PayPal totally?

Thanks - Joe

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should suffice:

To filter out a referring source from your reports, create the following filter:

Filter Type: Custom Filter > Exclude

Filter Field: Campaign Source

Filter Pattern: Enter the domain of the referring source that you would like to exclude, for example, `paypal.com`. You can use regular expressions if you would like to exclude several referring sources.

Comment: Thanks. I've set it up and will let you know whether this works or not. As you know, they can't be applied retroactively, so I have to wait a day or so and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it. I'm still getting PayPal referrals. A number from /cgibin/webscr and the other from us/cgi-bin/webscr. The regex I used was .*paypal.com/.* - shouldn't that cover both of those paths?

Answer (score 0):

If you check https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en
It will tell you to:

1. Navigate to a property. If you're not in the settings screen, click
   Admin.
2. Click Tracking Info then Referral Exclusion List.
3. Enter the Domain.
4. Click Apply to save.